# Auto Layout a background image to work on all devices

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a background image in my app. I want this image to fill the screen on all devices (iphone and ipad) and all sizes. It doesn't matter if the aspect ratio is changed (it's a gradient image). Been trying to do this with auto layout but can get it to work :(

Comment: `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to set the top, leading (left), trailing (right) and bottom attributes to be equal to that of their parent view which itself must be "full screen".

You probably need to set the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` too. E.g.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

More information on `contentMode` can be found in the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode) for `UIView`